# Function for generate a huge and possible random relationship between tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, functions

I have this two tables and N:M relationship between them:

[image]

Let's said I am managed to create a lot of `media` and `emails` records but I need to create the relationship between them. I can do this programmatically but I don't want to waste time on that if I can do in someway using MySQL functions or any other way. So, any advice, code example, query example?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea and if I can get real rows id (from media and emails tables) better

Comment: Lets said 100 relations, but would be better if I can made a COUNT first and then use that result for max to add

Comment: Lets said ~2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that the `media` tables has 1K rows and the `emails` one has 100K rows.

Then this will insert into the `emails_media_xref` all possible combinations, 1K x 100K = 100M, that is a hundred million rows.
**Warning, this may take some time**:

```
INSERT INTO emails_media_xref
    (emails_id, media_id)
SELECT 
    emails.id, media.id 
FROM emails 
  CROSS JOIN 
     media ;
```

If you want to insert a row for every email, that is 100K rows (random, different choice of `media` per email):

```
INSERT INTO emails_media_xref
    (emails_id, media_id)
SELECT 
    emails.id, 
    ( SELECT media.id
      FROM media
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 1
    ) 
FROM emails ;
```

If you want to insert (up to) `@N` rows for every email, that is a  maximum of N x 100K rows (random, different choices of `media` per email). This will not be exactly N rows per email because of the duplicates (which the `DISTINCT` will remove):

```
INSERT INTO emails_media_xref
    (emails_id, media_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
    emails.id, 
    ( SELECT media.id
      FROM media
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 1
    ) 
FROM emails 
  CROSS JOIN 
    ( SELECT 1
      FROM media
      LIMIT @N           -- pick a @N here
    ) AS x ;
```

If you want to insert a fixed number of rows, say 2000, totally randomly.
**Warning, this may take even more time than the first query**:

```
INSERT INTO emails_media_xref
    (emails_id, media_id)
SELECT 
    emails.id, media.id 
FROM emails 
  CROSS JOIN 
     media 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2000 ;
```

Comment: Excellent answer, many thanks, works perfectly